# Change Phone Number Stored On Sim

Tags: functionality

Is it possible to change the phone number that is stored on the sim card using a WP7 Phone (specifically the Nokia Lumia 800). I know its possible with some android phones.

Reasoning behind this is that I transferred old number to a new sim, but the sim card still shows the old number. The mobile carrier (orange UK) tried and failed to change it.

I have got a replacement fixed Sim now, but was wondering WP7 is capable of this?

Comment: AFAIK the new Tango version of Windows Phone will bring some SIM applications. Your phone has this option?

Comment: My phone does have a "Sim Applications" option in settings. There are just dumb generic apps contained in it, but nothing about changing information stored on the sim.

Comment: Where was it showing the "wrong" number?

Comment: There is a "Phone Number" stored on the SIM card actually, which indeed can be different from the number on the network. It can be modified pretty easily on any Blackberry all other platforms appear to need a custom app.

Comment: @RowlandShaw It is in Settings -> about -> more information -> MDN

Answer (score 4):

This is going to be tough to answer as we can only answer as to our phone/carrier combination.

I have seen the HD7, on T-Mobile, the Titan, Focus, and HD7s on ATT, and none were able to do that. I have also never read of that as part of the device, and never seen it talked about on review sites like WpCentral, or turned up anything on a web search.

I have to come to the conclusion that you can't. However, there may be a carrier that would let you. I doubt it though as the SIM is the link to your account, and you can't really go changing the number all willy-nilly.

Sorry, but I don't believe it can be done.

Comment: Yeah, SIM stand for Subscriber Identity Module, and what number is tied to it should be under the control of the phone network company and not the user, I would have thought.

Comment: +1 Wasn't sure if their could potentially have been a diagnostics mode on the phone that could do this, although I believe these modes and getting access to them are manufacturer/phone specific.

Answer (score 0):

It's the MDN that is being talked about here. When you get a brand new SIM card with a new number, most likely, your new number will be stored in the SIM card by default and you need not change it. However, if you replaced your SIM card with a blank SIM card or if you ported you number to another operator, you would have a SIM card with either no MDN or a temporary MDN stored on it. All handsets display the stored MDN either under "My Numbers" (Multi-SIM handsets) or under "My Phone Number", however, not all handsets allow you to edit the stored MDN. If you have a Samsung handset, you can edit the number by going to "Contacts" >> "Settings" >> "My Numbers".